# RegEx to check whether string has lower case letter after a space

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to identify if a string has lower case letter after a space in a string.

Example: In the string `John Fitzgerald Kennedy`, I want to identify whether `J`, `F`, `K` are in lower or upper case.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I fixed the typesetting and shortened the title. Please follow the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use the character classes to do that:

- `\p{Ll}` or `\p{Lowercase_Letter}` will match any Unicode lower case character. It's far safer than using `[a-z]` as `äéã` are also lower case chars but would not match if you use just characters a to z.
- `\p{Lu}` or `\p{Uppercase_Letter}` is the same for uppercase Unicode chars.

Example in application: https://regex101.com/r/uUIawr/2

Documentation about it: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html